# Positioning x axis labels in a single line in Google column chart

Tags: google-visualization

The Column chart I'm plotting using google visualization API shows x-axis label in two lines

[image]

In above image label are placed alternatively. I want to place it in single line.

```
hAxis: { showTextEvery: !0, title: c }, chartArea: { left: "20%", width: "100%", height: "70%", top: "0%", right: "1%"}
```

above option I'm passing to google column chart API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is placed alternatively because names are too long I guess.

Whith highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/ ) it's what happend. 
If names are too long, they are displayed in 2 lines else in a single line.

Comment: using google column chart can I trim x-axis label? can I format and set no of character to display?

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#ColumnStyles Look for "Labelling column"

Comment: in the "Element" section write "" ? (I never tried this appi)